# Statistic Missing Value

Tags: statistics, average

A professor has recorded exam grades for $30$ students in his class, $1$ of the $30$ grades is unreadable. The mean score on the exam was $82$, and the mean score of the $29$ available scores is $84$,

What is the value of the unreadable score?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How the sample mean changes when you add a new observation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198469/how-the-sample-mean-changes-when-you-add-a-new-observation)

Comment: Note that while one of the questions is expressed in terms of adding a new value and the other in terms of a value going missing, in both cases the mean of $n+1$ values is to be calculated based on the $(n+1)$-th value and the mean of $n$ values.

Answer (score 5):

$$
82=\text{mean score}=\frac{\text{sum of all scores}}{30}=\frac{\text{missing score}+\text{sum of all others}}{30}.
$$
Therefore
$$
30\cdot82 = \text{missing score}+\text{sum of all others}.
$$
$$
30\cdot82=\text{missing score}+\left(29\cdot\text{mean of all others}\right)= \text{missing score}+(29\cdot84).
$$
So
$$
30\cdot82=\text{missing score}+(29\cdot84).
$$
Can you find the missing score given that?

Answer (score 0):

If our missing person's grade was $84$, the average would be $84$.  But the average is $82$. To bring down the average to $82$, the missing person must have received a grade of $(2)(30)$ **below** $84$.